# Spinner with custom background and with triangle

Tags: android, spinner

Android 6.0+, Java 1.8.
In my android app.

Here my custom layout xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:binding="http://www.gueei.com/android-binding/"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerAmount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/send_editAmount"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:background="@drawable/backwithborder_notfocus"
                binding:text="amount" >
            </EditText>

            <View
                android:layout_width="8dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@drawable/backwithborder_notfocus" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/currencySpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here my custom drawable `backwithborder_notfocus.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- background color -->
    <solid android:color="#FAFAF8" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#CCCCCC" />

</shape>
```

And here result on Android 6.0

[image]

As you can see the triangle is not in the corner. Also has one more bottom line. How I can fix this?
Edit text has same background.

Comment: Show the full xml code.

Comment: @UmangBurman I update my post

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Change this:

```
 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/currencySpinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To:

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/currencySpinner"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Alexei Your spinner by default will only go upto that much.. It will not touch the relative layout fully.

Comment: @Alexei The default spinner will not touch at the end, and the line also will be there above a little.

Comment: @Alexei You can only do that if you make a custom spinner

Comment: Not need custom spinner. I add my  answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/racommon_backwithborder_notfocus" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/currencySpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_popup" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And now it's like I want:

[image]

Comment: Okay Good.. i appreciate that